# Why said a virtual thread still runs code on an OS thread?

Tags: java, multithreading, jvm, virtual-threads

I am learning about Java virtual threads, and I'm very confused because of this sentence:

> A virtual thread still runs code on an OS thread.

[According to the documentation provided by Oracle, a virtual thread still runs code on an OS thread.](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/core/virtual-threads.html#GUID-DC4306FC-D6C1-4BCC-AECE-48C32C1A8DAA)

I think a virtual thread runs code on an platform thread, because according to the documentation provided by Oracle, when the Java runtime schedules a virtual thread, it assigns or mounts the virtual thread on a platform thread, then the operating system schedules that platform thread as usual.

How do I understand that?

Comment: "platform thread", "os thread" and "native thread" are all just different terms for the same thing.

Comment: You are correct in your understanding that virtual threads execute code on platform threads provided by the operating system. These virtual threads offer a higher-level abstraction that simplifies concurrency management, without the intricacies of dealing directly with native threads.

Comment: All user-space code that runs does so in an OS process/thread. The doc is saying that the code will run *somewhere*. But you cannot point to a specific OS thread that will provide that somewhere. The JVM may move the execution around over time across a pool of its OS threads.